# How can I treat a date string as a formatted array [YEAR,MONTH,DAY]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, split

I have element that stores a date as a string like this

```
2015,4,06
```

How can I convert it to array like this?

```
[2015,4,06]
```

I have a script that accept the date as array [YEAR,MONTH,DAY] but I can't figure how to convert the string format into array accepted format with [] wrapping the date.

I have tried new Date( .. ) but that's not what I am trying to do, I am looking for a way to make the string read as array [YEAR,MONTH,DAY]

How can I do that? I tried:

JSON.parse, toArray, etc but I am sure all that stuff is invalid methods. am I missing something so simple?

Thank you!

Comment: This question isn't at all related to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = '2015,4,06';
var array = date.split(',');
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method which returns array like this:

```
var str="2015,4,06";
var array = str.split(","); //here is your array`
```